# how to make previously entered values appear for multistep forms after validation errors

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-forms

so evidently if I turn a form into a multistep form:

```
  if(!isset($form_state['storage']['step']))
    $form_state['storage']['step'] = 1;
```

and do `form_set_error()` in validate

when the validation error appears, the values that I previously put in would disappear.....

so If I enter a value into a textbox in a multistep form then hit continue then validation error appears, the textbox will now be empty instead of being filled with my previously entered values as it would happen normally

is there a way to prevent this from happening without manually reentering the default values for every form element?

fyi I'm using drupal 6

Comment: gee did you copy and past that right?

Comment: I love Drupal but I don't know too much about this problem... Anyway... have you tried prepopulating the fields with the submitted post values? If your fields are simple you can use prepopulate module, or something like that... Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the default value of the textfield with its value that is submitted in the form_state array like it is $form_state['values']['textfield name']['#value'].Then the submitted value is appeared in it.You can also get more help from the http://drupal.org/project/examples